# Filter array of custom objects with a dictionary property

Tags: objective-c, filter

I have an array that holds MyCustomObject objects.

MyCustomObject has 3 properties:

```
NSString *id;
NSString *name;
NSDictionary *phones;
```

How do I filter that array by the content of the "phones" property?

All I saw online is:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phones CONTAINS[c] %@",textField.text];
self.filteredArray = [self.unfilteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But it doesn't help me much...

Thanks

Comment: can you please tell that 'phones' is a dictionary object or 'NSString' object? as you mentioned above that it is dictionary object. I doubt it for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyCustomObject *value = [[MyCustomObject alloc] init];
for(value in arrayname)
{
    NSString *str = [value.phones objectForKey:@"key"];
    NSRange r = [str rangeOfString:textField.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(r.location != NSNotFound)
    {
       NSLog(@"Match found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.filterArray = [self.unfilteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
      MyCustomObject *obj = (MyCustomObject*)evaluatedObject;
         return ([[[obj.phones objectForKey:@"key"] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[textField.text lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound );

  }]];
```

Comment: I'm actually looking inside all the values of the dictionary to see if the value is there. If you'll show me how you do that, i'll be happy to grade you up. Thanks!